# Fancybox/Fancyapp Scrollbars for YouTube iFrame -- showing in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, iframe, youtube, fancybox

I am seeing scrollbars show up on my Fancyapps popup -- when I'm using iframe and linking to a YouTube video.  I have scrollbars set to no.  I see this in Firefox even using the Fancyapps site (see YouTube example here: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples).

Any ideas on how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Firefox 26+?

It's a bit of a long story but this behavior seems to be related to Firefox `ontouchstart` settings.

I ran into this issue when writing a script to detect `ontouchstart` events on mobile devices. After upgrading to Firefox version 26, the script returned `true` even on desktop devices.

For reasons that are still unknown to me, the property `dom.w3c_touch_events.enabled` was set to `1` (*enabled*) on Firefox of my desktop <strike>(maybe I changed it previously but it didn't affect until I upgraded)</strike>

**EDIT** : There were changes to the [Responsive Design View](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_View) feature in Firefox 26 and it seems that the updates may have enabled the `dom.w3c_touch_events.enabled` property.

Setting the value to `0` (or `2` for auto-detection), will fix the double vertical scrollbars on (Fancybox) iframes.

So try this :

1). In the Firefox URL bar write `about:config`

You will get a warning message :

> ```
> This might void your warranty!
> Changing this advanced settings can be harmful to....
> ```

2). Click the `I'll be carefull, I promise` button. Then you will get the list of all Firefox properties.

3). On the top `search` bar, enter `dom.w3c_touch_events.enabled` and you will filter the list to that property.

My guess is that the value of your Firefox (last column) is set to `1`.

4). To change it, doubleclick on the property and it will popup a window where you can set the value to `0`(or `2` for auto-detection). Press `OK` then.

You can close this window/tab now and reload the fancybox (Fancyapps) page. The double scrollbar should be gone.

**NOTE**: Do it at your own risk. I assume no liability for any misuse of the advanced settings ;)